# Passing a table as variable for looping in mysql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I want to store the result of my stored procedure based on the table passed as a parameter and then make a loop from it so that I can update the selected rows.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `close_transaction_procedure`(IN `tablename` VARCHAR(100), IN `businessdate_column` VARCHAR(40), IN `primary_number` VARCHAR(30), IN `lead_time` INT)
BEGIN

SET @strprd = CONCAT('SELECT ',primary_number, ', status_code FROM ',tablename,' WHERE ',businessdate_column ,' < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ', lead_time ,' DAY)');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @strprd;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

-- loop based on results of execute stmt1

END
```

Comment: the problem is you can't pass the table name as variable, or you don't know how to store the results and make the loop?

Comment: TBH its my first stored procedure task, though i know how to make a loop if the code is similar to this:

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM account WHERE date_of_birth = '0000-00-00';

but since that code cannot use a parameter as the table name i used 
SET @strprd = CONCAT() statement... 

Sorry if my english is bad.. anyway thanks!

Comment: i want to store the results and make a loop

Comment: what do you want update?

Comment: i want to know how to get the results of 'EXECUTE stmt1;' then make a loop so that i can update the status of each row based on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to update without a loop, using a temporary table to store the results of the select:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `close_transaction_procedure`(IN `tablename` VARCHAR(100), IN `businessdate_column` VARCHAR(40), IN `primary_number` VARCHAR(30), IN `lead_time` INT)
BEGIN

/* create a temporary table where you'll store your select's result */
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_records;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_records
(
  primary_number VARCHAR(100),
  status_code VARCHAR(100)
);

/* store the result of the select into temp_records with the INSERT...SELECT construct */
SET @strprd = CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp_records(primary_number, status_code) SELECT ',primary_number, ', status_code FROM ',tablename,' WHERE ',businessdate_column ,' < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ', lead_time ,' DAY)');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @strprd;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

/* now that you have your result in temp_records table, you can update without a loop, using temp_records table as reference */

END
```

Comment: Thanks @xcloudx, I'll get back to you the result! THANKS! :)

Comment: I don't know why but after running the procedure i get a Error Code: 1327. Undeclared variable: temp_records, i already checked if i missed someting

Comment: i've changed the insert query in my example, retry now

Comment: oh thanks, i also found the answer here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html, the right syntax should be insert - select. thanks man!